# Difference between @pathparam and @QueryParam in resteasy

Tags: java-ee-6

I am the new one for developing Resteasy .i don't know the difference between @pathparam and @Queryparam .which one is best?

Answer (score 1):

The @PathParam annotation binds the value of a path segment to a resource method parameter. if you @Path("login/{zip}"), HTTP GET like `http://server:port/login/12345`, @PathParam("zip") is 12345

The @QueryParam annotation binds the value of a path segment to a resource method parameter. if you @Path("login"),  HTTP GET like `http://server:port/login?id=12345`, @QueryParam("id") is 12345